Кнопка, при нажатии которой будет меняться тип диаграммы
В общем нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку менялся тип диаграммы, как это можно сделать? Пока что накидал вот такой код:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace Diagrama
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text), Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text));
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (chart1.Series[0].ChartType == SeriesChartType.Line)
            {
                chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
            }
            else if (chart1.Series[0].ChartType == SeriesChartType.Pie)
            {
                chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
            }
        }
    }
}



И что? Этот код не работает?

сама кнопка, которая должна менять диаграмму не работает, остальное все в норме

А обработчик события вообще вызывается? Вставьте в него логирование или MessagBox.
